# Advanced org mode templating: a jinja-like system possible?

Tags: org-mode

I use org-mode for notes and technical content writing. I find myself frequently copy-pasting snippets and changing values within this region. For example, a table whose cells change, but dimensions and headers remain the same. Is there a way to create a jinja-like template that will *update* based on input values?

The key here is *update*. What I cannot use:

1. Macros. These will simply insert static text. If I want to change the template, I will have the do this manually at each place, i.e. I'm looking for a solution that minimizes work not only at *creation* but also updating.
2. Yas snippets. Again, static text problem

How can I do this in org-mode?

Comment: What you are trying to do is unclear to me. What do things look like before the update and what do they look like after the update? How is the update to be triggered?

Comment: What I'm trying to do: something close to the leo-editor.
Another way to think about it: what if I have a jinja template file and I want to reuse over a single org file with different parameters.
I'm assuming you are familiar with templating systems in general.